# is there a way to change the size of hats?

Tags: feature-request, hats

I got a hat that has ears but it's too big for my head

...so is it possible to make it smaller? I think this feature is crucial if it doesn't exist.

Comment: You can move them around over your avatar, but I don't think you can resize them.

Comment: I know I can :)

Comment: As hats are a) for fun only and b) shortlived I don't see much value in putting additional effort into their appearance :-)

Comment: ...I think this one feature is worth it because there are some hats that can't be used without resizing. ... it _is_ short-lived though!

Comment: The hat can't be resized, but your head can be. (I meant the picture of your head of course.)

Comment: LOL yeah I thought of that but I have my account connected to my facebook account so I need to alter my facebook profile picture to do that.